# Is it possible to export data from .then function?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am working with Node and MSSQL Server using the mssql module. When consuming a promise, I would like to **export or return data from the .then function**. Is this possible or are there any workarounds?

```
getDb = function(){

// This code establishes connection to SQL Server

  const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
  const req = new sql.Request(conn)
  conn.connect()
  .then(function getData (req) {

// This code makes query to SQL Server

      req.query("SELECT * FROM USER")
      .then(function(res){

      console.log(res) // logs Correct User
      module.exports.user = res // logs undefined in main.js

      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }
  )
  .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
}
getDb()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No because the value you're trying to export is asynchronous. You can't export in the present a value that you will get in the future.

Comment: Why not export the getDb function and returning the value you want to export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way you can export the getDb function and import and consume it to the the data:

```
exports.getDb = () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
      const req = new sql.Request(conn)
      conn.connect().then(req => {
        return req.query("SELECT * FROM USER")
      }).then(res => {
        return resolve(res);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, didnt think about that! works like a charm!